# How do javascript closures work with objects

Tags: javascript, closures

```
function add(_abc) {
    return _abc.b = 10;
}

var abc = { a: 5 };

(function(abc){
    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(`abc from inside function ${JSON.stringify(abc)}`);
    }, 3000);
})(abc);

add(abc);

console.log(`abc from outside function ${JSON.stringify(abc)}`);
```

Produces the output

```
abc from outside function {"a":5,"b":10} 
abc from inside function {"a":5,"b":10}
```

I want to display the console output from the inside function without `b`

Comment: `abc = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(abc));` before the timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the stringified version of `abc` as a closure instead of the reference to the object:

```js
function add(_abc) {
  return _abc.b = 10;
}

var abc = { a: 5 };

(function(abc) {
  let abc_str = JSON.stringify(abc)
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(`abc from inside function ${abc_str}`);
  }, 3000);
})(abc);

add(abc);

console.log(`abc from outside function ${JSON.stringify(abc)}`);
```

Closures bind names, they don't freeze objects. So there isn't a way to get a snapshot of the state of an object in a closure without making a copy, which is what we are basically doing by stringifying it.